# Как избавиться от наследования?

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура, наследование, шаблоны-проектирования

Проблема такая: у меня есть алгоритм, и есть 2 различные реализации алгоритма. Эти реализации надо вызывать из многих мест в зависимости от режима, выбранного пользователем. Не хотелось бы во всех местах, где вызываются реализации писать условные операторы. Поэтому я создал абстрактный класс, а реализации наследуют от него. В одном месте я проверяю так:

```
    if(firstMode){
        list = new ListForm1();
    }
    else{
        list = new LiastForm2();
    }
```

А дальше во всех местах пользуюсь всеми преимуществами полиморфизма. Хотелось бы избавиться от наследования по трем причинам:

1. Постоянно говорят что композиция всегда лучше наследования.
2. Первая форма алгоритма намного проще, чем вторая. В ней всего 3 метода, а во второй 15. В абстрактный класс пришлось включить все 15 (ну и еще 5 там есть общих методов). Получается что 12 методов не используются первой формой.
3. Теоретически, может появиться новая форма алгоритма, которая будет иметь еще меньше общего с двумя другими, зато привнесет 10 новых методов и их все придется добавлять в абстрактный класс.

Паттерн стратегия, как я понимаю, особого смысла тут не имеет. Приведу его пример с [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), что бы лучше описать свои сомнения:

```
// Класс реализующий конкретную стратегию, должен реализовывать этот интерфейс
// Класс контекста использует этот интерфейс для вызова конкретной стратегии
interface Strategy {
    int execute(int a, int b); 
}

// Реализуем алгоритм с использованием интерфейса стратегии
class ConcreteStrategyAdd implements Strategy {

    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategyAdd's execute()");
        return a + b;  // Do an addition with a and b
    }
}

class ConcreteStrategySubtract implements Strategy {

    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategySubtract's execute()");
        return a - b;  // Do a subtraction with a and b
    }
}

class ConcreteStrategyMultiply implements Strategy {

    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called ConcreteStrategyMultiply's execute()");
        return a * b;   // Do a multiplication with a and b
    }    
}

// Класс контекста использующий интерфейс стратегии
class Context {

    private Strategy strategy;

    // Constructor
    public Context() {
    }

    // Set new strategy
    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public int executeStrategy(int a, int b) {
        return strategy.execute(a, b);
    }
}
```

Все те же проблемы остаются. Стратегии то должны быть связаны между собой. Если связывать их будет интерфейс, а не абстрактный класс, то только хуже. В интерфейсе по-прежнему будет очень много методов, при этом первой форме алгоиртма многие из них будут не нужны. К тому же придется дублировать общие методы во всех стратегиях, их уже не удастся вынести в интерфейс.

А как здесь воспользоваться композицией я совсем не понимаю. В моем понимаю в паттерне стратегия уже используется композиция. В классе `Context`. Он же содержит переменную класса `Strategy`. Хотя возможно это делегирование.

В общем, вопрос такой:

*Можно ли мне избавиться от всех вышеописанных проблем (перегруженный методами абстрактный класс, сильная связанность, из-за которой может быть сложно добавить новую форму алгоритма), но при этом по-прежнему использовать условные операторы только в одном месте, а не во всех случаях, когда мне нужна та или иная форма алгоритма (потому что так они дублируются по всей программе).*

Comment: По моему надо глянуть ширше: Если и тот и другой алгоритм, в зависимости от условий
    используются в разных местах, то зачем вы унифицируете код на уровне
    алгоритма, а не на уровне его реализации? Итог же и там и там в одном
    и том же виде должен быть возвращен?

Comment: Нет нет, говоря "алгоритм" я имею в виду код, реализующих его.

Comment: Сударь, хватит тут "словестных химер" порождать! "у меня есть алгоритм, и есть 2 различные реализации алгоритма" + "говоря "алгоритм" я имею в виду код, реализующих его". Это что за рекурсия!? Может хватит тут томик войны и мира порождать, а структуру кода показать? Хотябы упрощенную.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim, код на 2000 строк, я и не знаю что показать. Алгоритм - это просто математика. Ну я это имел в виду. Просто записанный на бумаге алгоритм. А классы, которые я называл алгоритмами - это реализации записанного на бумаге алгоритма.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров что такое "форма алгоритма" в вашем вопросе? это реализация алгоритма? или форма, из которой реализация вызывается?

Comment: Тут дело не в "Войне и мире", а просто в неверном использовании терминов: многие абстракции выражаются одним неконкретным словом "алгоритм". У вас есть **интерфейс** и две его **реализации**. Старайтесь использовать наиболее конкретные термины и не дублировать словами то, что в коде уже написано.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров судя по всему, у вас есть две формы, в каждой из которых просто пачка методов, и нет как такового общего интерфейса. И в тех местах, где вызываются 12 из 15 "лишних" методов, первая форма просто не будет ничего делать (и скорее всего реально такой ситуации не возникает, т.к. вы всегда используете там вторую форму, но, зачем-то, через абстрактного родителя). Как-то так?

Comment: @PashaPash, да, все абсолютно верно. А через абстрактного родителя - это что бы полиморфизмом воспользоваться, а не писать в 10 местах условные операторы.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров но при этом в тех местах, где вызываются 12 из 15 методов - полиморфизм вам не нужен. Он там просто не работает. Зачем же вы работаете там с конкретным типом (второй формой) через родителя? Не проще ли работать там с второй формой напрямую? А в абстрактном классе (интерфейсе) оставить три общих метода.

Comment: @PashaPash, даже так, у меня есть 2 реализации алгоритма (2 класса), и 2 класса GUI, из которых эти алгоритмы вызываются (тоже 2 класса). Но и в реализациях алгоритма и в классах GUI у меня есть кое-что общее (и не мало), поэтому я делаю иерархию наследования (даже 2 получается) что бы не дублировать это общее.

Comment: @PashaPash, то есть в каждой форме можно сделать ссылку на конкретную реализацию алгоритма, а не на родителя?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров если каждая форма соответствует конкретному алгоритму - то да

Comment: @PashaPash, точно) спасибо большое)